# Is there any way to do a WER "Request Additional Files" for the windows temp directory?

Tags: windows-error-reporting, winqual

My company has had numerous crashes reported to windows error reporting due to what looks like an install problem.  The logs for our installs are typically in the windows\temp directory.  I would like to include the install log file as a "Request Additional Files" entry, however there doesn't seem to be any way to get to a subdirectory of the list of environmental Variables that are provided.  The windows temp directory is not in the list of values that you can work from, so I am stuck.

In general, I don't understand how it is possible to get at almost anything of use via the "Request Additional Files".  For example, the %programfiles% directory shouldn't contain any useful files, they should be in a subdirectory for your product.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this?

Comment: I was never able to find a solution to this issue.

Comment: They pulled support for xp, so all the effort we put into this was wasted :(

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this works but could you try  %programfiles%/../../ (or something similar)
using the know location/depth of the programfiles folder (or which ever variable you use) and navigate up to the root (by having the correct number of "../") and the add your extra from there?

So to get to C:\TempData you might have something like:

%programfiles%/../TempData

One thing to consider is that this path might vary on different versions of Windows...

Like I said, this is a suggestion...

Comment: I just tested this but it does not work.  Winqual does not allow the following characters: "*/:?"\<>|;"  Which is a bit of a pain.